# The authentication or decryption has failed with Nuget on macOS (mono) on repo with Letsencrypt certificate

Tags: ssl, mono, nuget, macos-sierra, lets-encrypt

We use our own repository for nuget packages (Nexus3 from Sonatype). Without SSL certificate it was working well.

Now we decided to make our repo reachable over the internet for developers that are not in the office. We want to use Letsencrypt certificates. This works well. The web interface is OK and we can communicate from Visual Studio to the repositoreis.

If we try to connect to the repo from mac (macOS 10.12.1), the connection fails (no matter under Nuget CLI, from Xamaris Studio or paket).

**Versions:**

```
osx-build-agent:bin buildagent$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.2 (mono-4.6.0-branch/08fd525 Thu Nov 10 20:28:28 EST 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-master/8b1520c)
    GC:            sgen

osx-build-agent:tools buildagent$ mono NuGet.exe
NuGet Version: 3.4.3.855
usage: NuGet <command> [args] [options] 
Type 'NuGet help <command>' for help on a specific command.
```

I tiried `tlstest.exe` from mono tools and got th following error:

```
FAILED: #-2146233079
System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0003a] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:430 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:256 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:418 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00035] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:396 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslStreamBase.cs:101 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00051] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslStreamBase.cs:883 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/LegacySslStream.cs:475 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/LegacySslStream.cs:445 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x0001e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MonoTlsStream.cs:99 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1023 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:1037 
  at TlsTest.GetWebPage (System.String url) [0x000a2] in /Users/buildagent/Projects/SSLTest/SSLTest/Program.cs:184 
  at TlsTest.Main (System.String[] args) [0x002c0] in /Users/buildagent/Projects/SSLTest/SSLTest/Program.cs:143
```

The same happens, if I try this tool to connect to the known web sites, that uses Letsencryp certificates (e.g. https://community.letsencrypt.org).

I already tried the following without success:

- `mozroots --import --sync`
- `mozroots --import  --sync --machine` (doesn't work on macOS)
- `certmgr -ssl https://letsencrypt.org` and accepted three authorities
- `certmgr -ssl https://community.letsencrypt.org` and our repo site.

The last ended always with:

```
Mono Certificate Manager - version 4.6.2.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.


Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket has been shut down. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The socket has been shut down
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndSend (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00033] in <bd46d4d4f7964dfa9beea098499ab597>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndWrite (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005f] in <bd46d4d4f7964dfa9beea098499ab597>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndWrite (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x000af] in <bd46d4d4f7964dfa9beea098499ab597>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndSendRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendRecord (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData) [0x0000b] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Alert alert) [0x00027] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (System.Exception& ex) [0x00021] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndNegotiateHandshake (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase+InternalAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00028] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.NegotiateHandshake () [0x00035] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x00076] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush (System.Boolean flushStream, System.Boolean flushEncoder) [0x00094] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush () [0x00006] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.GetCertificatesFromSslSession (System.String url) [0x00093] in <facd5c0e258a4f19ba1c49a19b1b0dc1>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Ssl (System.String host, System.Boolean machine, System.Boolean verbose) [0x00028] in <facd5c0e258a4f19ba1c49a19b1b0dc1>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00216] in <facd5c0e258a4f19ba1c49a19b1b0dc1>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Error while sending TLS Alert (Fatal:InternalError): System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket has been shut down. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The socket has been shut down
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndSend (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00033] in <bd46d4d4f7964dfa9beea098499ab597>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndWrite (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005f] in <bd46d4d4f7964dfa9beea098499ab597>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndWrite (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x000af] in <bd46d4d4f7964dfa9beea098499ab597>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndSendRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendRecord (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ContentType contentType, System.Byte[] recordData) [0x0000b] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Alert alert) [0x00027] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.SendAlert (System.Exception& ex) [0x00021] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndNegotiateHandshake (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase+InternalAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00028] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.NegotiateHandshake () [0x00035] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x00076] in <1d0bb82c94e7435eb09324cf5ef20e36>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush (System.Boolean flushStream, System.Boolean flushEncoder) [0x00094] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush () [0x00006] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.GetCertificatesFromSslSession (System.String url) [0x00093] in <facd5c0e258a4f19ba1c49a19b1b0dc1>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Ssl (System.String host, System.Boolean machine, System.Boolean verbose) [0x00028] in <facd5c0e258a4f19ba1c49a19b1b0dc1>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00216] in <facd5c0e258a4f19ba1c49a19b1b0dc1>:0
```

What should I do to make nuget runnig on macOS (with Letsencrypt certificates)?

**Edit:**

**Mono 4.8 behaviour**

```
osx-build-agent:bin buildagent$ ./mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.8.0 (mono-4.8.0-branch/f5fbc32 Mon Nov 14 14:10:00 EST 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-master/8b1520c)
    GC:            sgen

osx-build-agent:bin buildagent$ ./certmgr -ssl https://community.letsencrypt.org
Mono Certificate Manager - version 4.8.0.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.


Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndNegotiateHandshake (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase+InternalAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00028] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.NegotiateHandshake () [0x00035] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x00076] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush (System.Boolean flushStream, System.Boolean flushEncoder) [0x00094] in <829ce140006e4cad9124766ee7f51179>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush () [0x00006] in <829ce140006e4cad9124766ee7f51179>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.GetCertificatesFromSslSession (System.String url) [0x00093] in <8f0191f2d4224208a456d99f3d667fc2>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Ssl (System.String host, System.Boolean machine, System.Boolean verbose) [0x00028] in <8f0191f2d4224208a456d99f3d667fc2>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00216] in <8f0191f2d4224208a456d99f3d667fc2>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00040] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0003b] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndNegotiateHandshake (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase+InternalAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00028] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.NegotiateHandshake () [0x00035] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x00076] in <4d95459e5c814a5dad6816d7b3a5a54b>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush (System.Boolean flushStream, System.Boolean flushEncoder) [0x00094] in <829ce140006e4cad9124766ee7f51179>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush () [0x00006] in <829ce140006e4cad9124766ee7f51179>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.GetCertificatesFromSslSession (System.String url) [0x00093] in <8f0191f2d4224208a456d99f3d667fc2>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Ssl (System.String host, System.Boolean machine, System.Boolean verbose) [0x00028] in <8f0191f2d4224208a456d99f3d667fc2>:0 
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00216] in <8f0191f2d4224208a456d99f3d667fc2>:0
```

Comment: What are your versions of `mono` and `nuget`?

Comment: @SushiHangover I added the version info above.

Comment: I would *assume* your server is TLS1.2 based? Also checkout Mono 4.8+ as on the mac, it now uses the the Apple cert store, no more mozroots ;-) .... Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Mac and the Mono installed by the official Mac MDK installer use Apple’s TLS stack instead which uses Apple’s system certificate store to resolve the root certificates, so everything works out of the box. : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.8.0/#tls-12-support

Comment: You can see the analysis of one of our domains with Letsencrypt certificate with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=git.schroeder.recy-systems.com

Comment: @SushiHangover I have Xamarin Studio installed with the default installer (the latest stable version). It doesn't work. I also install Mono 4.8 (with the preview of Microsoft Visual Studio for Mac), the same result. The server is configured to support TLS1, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 (nginx). ` ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;`

Comment: I'm still getting similar errors in Visual Studio for Mac (based on Xamarin Studio). `Error: SecureChannelFailure (Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.)` Same URL works fine in VS2017 on Windows

Comment: started getting a similiar issue on a machine that was netbooted to an old image.  like you, the common fix for these errors using cert-sync and mozroots --imports had no effect.   i did something similiar to you, ran certmgr -ssl on the end host, which failed witih same error as you.  then looked at cert and ran certmgr -ssl on every url up the chain.  when i ran it on digitcert.com, i got this message:

Answer (score 0):

started getting a similiar issue on a machine that was netbooted to an old image.

like you, the common fix for these errors using cert-sync and mozroots --imports had no effect.

i did something similar to you:

- ran certmgr -ssl on the end host, failed witih same error as you.
- then looked at cert for endhost and cert's issuers
- ran certmgr -ssl on every issuer url up the chain.

when i ran it on digitcert.com, i got this message:

```
X.509 Certificate v3
   Issued from: O=Digital Signature Trust Co., CN=DST Root CA X3
   Issued to:   C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=R3
   Valid from:  10/7/2020 7:21:40 PM
   Valid until: 9/29/2021 7:21:40 PM
   *** WARNING: Certificate isn't current ***
   *** WARNING: Certificate signature is INVALID **
```

I sort of recall some strange issues last year relating to digitcert issued certs tied to a particular date.

Then found these mono (and boring-ssl issues that describe same or similiar problems:

- https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/21253
- https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/21233
- https://github.com/KSP-CKAN/CKAN/pull/3457
- https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/19886

last one which references [the issue i vaguely recalled from end of 2021](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/).

This is same date as cert complained about above (tho too late to definately say the OP had exact same root cause).

The mono issues suggest various workarounds:
*blacklisting expired cert (so only new/cross-signed one is checked and allowed)

- using an external tool that doesn't have same cross-signing bug like curl (this appears to work)
- temporarily disabling certificate validation for single domains (if you can't do fix or previous 2 workarounds, and your security policies find this acceptable in your usage scenario).

The fix seems to be:

- cert-sync to get latest certs (which you probably already did if you found your way here like me)
- make sure openssl is a newer version (>=1.1) that does not have the cross-signing validation bug.

Latter seems to be the culprit on this older network image.